# Forcing precedence in arithmetic operations in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, math, canvas, operator-precedence

I'm trying to position a shape of size 10 pixels in relation to a square bitmap of width 72 pixels.

In the following code:

fShapeLocation refers to the final position of the shape

fBitmapWidth refers to the X width of the bitmap

cTopLeft.getX() is the top left corner of the bitmap

The object I'm adding should appear exactly 2/3+1/6th across the top X of the bitmap (just above the very center of the last third of the shape).

Something like this (^^^ is where I want it, and [] relates to the four corners of the bitmap square):

```
               ^^^
   [                ]


   [                ]


    fShapeLocation=this.cTopLeft.getX()+((this.fBitmapWidth/3)*2);
    fShapeLocation+=(fBitmapWidth/6)-5;
```

Notice how many brackets I tried to put in in order to force arithmetic precedence.

In practice, the shape appears about in the middle of the bitmap. I have a nasty suspicion that this is caused by the order in which java is evaluating the arithmetic expressions. I would rather shorten my code to just one line and have it place the shape in the right position - can anyone help me out? (My apologies that I was never very good at math)

Comment: Err, 2/3 plus 1/6 is 5/6. Those parentheses don't change the evaluation order. Your actual question remains unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to clarify - my question is whether using parenthesis will "force" java to evaluate the expression in the order that I want. For example: 3+4-2 -> (3+4)-2 vs 3+(4-2) - does the parenthesis force the compiler's evaluation order?

Comment: Of course they do: that's what they're for; but the ones you've added in the code you posted don't change the order in the code you posted. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write -5 when you meant *5? That would agree with your text. If so, your expression boils down to

```
fShapeLocation = c.topLeft.getX()+fBitmapWidth*5/6;
```

No parentheses at all, except for the method call. No need to change the evaluation order.